# c++ global variable result in segfault

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm working on turning some MCMC software written in c++ into an R-package using Rcpp and modules. In this regard I need to maintain a pointer that is a global variable, and that points to the latest object of some class constructed.

Here is a very simple example in the form of an R-script:

```
require(Rcpp)
require(inline)

inc <- '

using namespace Rcpp;

class test;
test* glob; //global pointer


class test{
  private: 
    double foo;
  public:
    test(double foo_) : foo(foo_) {
      glob=this; // the line causes segfault
    }; 
    double get_foo(){return foo;};
};

RCPP_MODULE(test){
  class_<test>("test")
  .constructor<double>()
  .property("foo",&test::get_foo)
  ;

}

'

fx <- cxxfunction(signature(),plugin="Rcpp",include=inc);
test_module <- Module("test",getDynLib(fx))
test <- test_module$test
t1 <- new(test,1.0)
```

What I'm trying to get at is something like the following (in c++):

```
#include<iostream>

class test;
test* glob;


class test{
  private: 
    double foo;
  public:
    test(double foo_) : foo(foo_) {glob=this;};
    double get_foo(){return foo;};
};

int main(){
  test t1(1.0);
  test t2(2.0);
  std::cout << (*glob).get_foo() << std::endl;
}
```

Which compiles and runs as it should.

Thanks in advance, 
Regards, Tore Kleppe

Comment: Adding an R tag as well...

Answer (score 2):

That seems like two unrelated and simple errors.

First off, you need to make that pointer `static`.  Things then work.

Second, using Rcpp Module with [inline](http://cran.r-project.org/package=inline) is no 
longer the easiest way around, and we generally recommend using a package -- or Rcpp Attributes as I do below.

Correct code, including explicit messaging to `stdout` in the constructor:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

class test;
static test* glob = NULL; //global pointer


class test{
  private: 
    double foo;
  public:
    test(double foo_) : foo(foo_) {
      Rcpp::Rcout << "Seeing foo_ of " << foo_ << " in ctor\n";
      glob=this; // the line causes segfault
    }; 
    double get_foo(){return foo;};
};

RCPP_MODULE(test){
  class_<test>("test")
  .constructor<double>()
  .property("foo",&test::get_foo)
  ;
}
```

Then simple use from the command-line (using littler; R or Rscript are equivalent):

```
$ r -lRcpp -e 'sourceCpp("/tmp/tore.cpp"); tt <- new(test, 1.23); print(tt$foo)'
Seeing foo_ of 1.23 in ctor
[1] 1.23
$
```

Note how we can skip all the Module instantiation etc.

Comment: Dirk; Thanks a lot! This saves my day. Regards -Tore

Comment: No sweat. Feel free, as is the custom here, to 'accept' the answer (click on the tick mark only you as the one asking it sees) and/or upvote it by clicking on the up-arrow.  That's how the site rolls. I had upvoted your question, by the way.